# mmap and then munmap, sometimes unmapped region can be accessed

Tags: linux, mmap

I met this problem on vmware 11.0 and linux-2.6.34, with gcc 4.9.2, had not tested on real hardware.
Following code run successfully and message were printed without SIGSEGV. But if I uncommented the printf before munmap, a SIGSEGV were caught.

maps before and after munmap() were printed in following messages.

```
static void check_mmap(void){
    int fd, i;
    char *p = NULL;

    if ((fd = shm_open("xxxxxxxxxxxx", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0666)) == -1) {
        printf("open shm file failed.\n");
        return;
    }

    if (ftruncate(fd, 4096) == -1)
        goto out;

    p = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
    if (MAP_FAILED == p)
    goto out;

    //printf("Mapped at %p\n", p);
    getchar(); // <----- chance to print maps befor munmap

    if (munmap(p, 4096) != 0)
        printf("munmap error: %s\n", strerror(errno));

    printf("Corrupting mmap memory.\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 4095; i ++)
        p[i] = 0;
    printf("Done\n");

    getchar(); // <----- chance to print maps after munmap

out:
    close(fd);
    if (p)
        munmap(p, 4096);
}
```

---

maps before munmap, shm xxxxxxxxxxxx is mmaped at 7f3f2683a000-7f3f2683b000

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 121 /mnt/hgfs/vm_shared/asan/asan1

00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:14 121 /mnt/hgfs/vm_shared/asan/asan1

7f3f25ea6000-7f3f25ebd000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f25ebd000-7f3f260bc000 ---p 00017000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f260bc000-7f3f260bd000 r--p 00016000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f260bd000-7f3f260be000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f260be000-7f3f260c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f260c2000-7f3f2620e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f2620e000-7f3f2640d000 ---p 0014c000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f2640d000-7f3f26411000 r--p 0014b000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f26411000-7f3f26412000 rw-p 0014f000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f26412000-7f3f26417000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f26417000-7f3f2641e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2641e000-7f3f2661d000 ---p 00007000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2661d000-7f3f2661e000 r--p 00006000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2661e000-7f3f2661f000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2661f000-7f3f2663d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 260202 /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so

7f3f2682b000-7f3f2682e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f26839000-7f3f2683a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f2683a000-7f3f2683b000 rw-p 00000000 00:11 16078 /dev/shm/xxxxxxxxxxxx

7f3f2683b000-7f3f2683c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f2683c000-7f3f2683d000 r--p 0001d000 08:02 260202 /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so

7f3f2683d000-7f3f2683e000 rw-p 0001e000 08:02 260202 /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so

7f3f2683e000-7f3f2683f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7fffd9ce3000-7fffd9d04000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]

7fffd9dff000-7fffd9e00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]

ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vsyscall]

---

maps after munmap, shm was successfully unmapped.

00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 121 /mnt/hgfs/vm_shared/asan/asan1

00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:14 121 /mnt/hgfs/vm_shared/asan/asan1

7f3f25ea6000-7f3f25ebd000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f25ebd000-7f3f260bc000 ---p 00017000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f260bc000-7f3f260bd000 r--p 00016000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f260bd000-7f3f260be000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 347266 /lib64/libpthread-2.11.3.so

7f3f260be000-7f3f260c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f260c2000-7f3f2620e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f2620e000-7f3f2640d000 ---p 0014c000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f2640d000-7f3f26411000 r--p 0014b000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f26411000-7f3f26412000 rw-p 0014f000 08:02 298091 /lib64/libc-2.11.1.so

7f3f26412000-7f3f26417000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f26417000-7f3f2641e000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2641e000-7f3f2661d000 ---p 00007000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2661d000-7f3f2661e000 r--p 00006000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2661e000-7f3f2661f000 rw-p 00007000 08:02 335978 /lib64/librt-2.11.1.so

7f3f2661f000-7f3f2663d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 260202 /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so

7f3f2682b000-7f3f2682e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f26839000-7f3f2683b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f2683b000-7f3f2683c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7f3f2683c000-7f3f2683d000 r--p 0001d000 08:02 260202 /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so

7f3f2683d000-7f3f2683e000 rw-p 0001e000 08:02 260202 /lib64/ld-2.11.1.so

7f3f2683e000-7f3f2683f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0

7fffd9ce3000-7fffd9d04000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 [stack]

7fffd9dff000-7fffd9e00000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vdso]

ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0 [vsyscall]

---

following is objdump

```
0000000000400890 <main>:
400890:       55                      push   %rbp
400891:       53                      push   %rbx
400892:       ba b6 01 00 00          mov    $0x1b6,%edx
400897:       be 42 02 00 00          mov    $0x242,%esi
40089c:       bf 9c 0a 40 00          mov    $0x400a9c,%edi
4008a1:       48 83 ec 08             sub    $0x8,%rsp
4008a5:       e8 fe fd ff ff          callq  4006a8 <shm_open@plt>
4008aa:       83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%eax
4008ad:       89 c3                   mov    %eax,%ebx
4008af:       0f 84 c0 00 00 00       je     400975 <main+0xe5>
4008b5:       be 00 10 00 00          mov    $0x1000,%esi
4008ba:       89 c7                   mov    %eax,%edi
4008bc:       e8 37 fe ff ff          callq  4006f8 <ftruncate@plt>
4008c1:       83 f8 ff                cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%eax
4008c4:       0f 84 9b 00 00 00       je     400965 <main+0xd5>
4008ca:       45 31 c9                xor    %r9d,%r9d
4008cd:       31 ff                   xor    %edi,%edi
4008cf:       41 89 d8                mov    %ebx,%r8d
4008d2:       b9 02 00 00 00          mov    $0x2,%ecx
4008d7:       ba 03 00 00 00          mov    $0x3,%edx
4008dc:       be 00 10 00 00          mov    $0x1000,%esi
4008e1:       e8 22 fe ff ff          callq  400708 <mmap@plt>
4008e6:       48 83 f8 ff             cmp    $0xffffffffffffffff,%rax
4008ea:       48 89 c5                mov    %rax,%rbp
4008ed:       0f 84 8e 00 00 00       je     400981 <main+0xf1>
4008f3:       48 8b 3d 0e 05 20 00    mov    0x20050e(%rip),%rdi        # 600e08   <__TMC_END__>
4008fa:       e8 b9 fd ff ff          callq  4006b8 <_IO_getc@plt>
4008ff:       be 00 10 00 00          mov    $0x1000,%esi
400904:       48 89 ef                mov    %rbp,%rdi
400907:       e8 dc fd ff ff          callq  4006e8 <munmap@plt>
40090c:       85 c0                   test   %eax,%eax
40090e:       75 7a                   jne    40098a <main+0xfa>
400910:       bf d1 0a 40 00          mov    $0x400ad1,%edi
400915:       e8 6e fd ff ff          callq  400688 <puts@plt>
40091a:       48 8d 8d ff 0f 00 00    lea    0xfff(%rbp),%rcx
400921:       48 89 ea                mov    %rbp,%rdx
400924:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
400928:       c6 02 00                movb   $0x0,(%rdx)
40092b:       48 83 c2 01             add    $0x1,%rdx
40092f:       48 39 ca                cmp    %rcx,%rdx
400932:       75 f4                   jne    400928 <main+0x98>
400934:       bf e9 0a 40 00          mov    $0x400ae9,%edi
400939:       e8 4a fd ff ff          callq  400688 <puts@plt>
40093e:       48 8b 3d c3 04 20 00    mov    0x2004c3(%rip),%rdi        # 600e08 <__TMC_END__>
400945:       e8 6e fd ff ff          callq  4006b8 <_IO_getc@plt>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're invoking "undefined behavior."  Anything could happen.  You can't then complain that in one case you like the result more than in another case when both have undefined behavior.  Just stop running invalid code.

Comment: I don't think this is an undefined behavior. If a region is unmapped, its discared out of process address space, any access to it must caught a SIGSEGV, except the same address range is used by another mmap.

Comment: @wuyabiao: do you have a link to any documentation that says SIGSEGV is guaranteed?  Did you know that on some systems (other than Linux), dereferencing a NULL pointer does not raise any signal?

Comment: What I means is that refence a unmaped region should cause process abort, bus error or sigsegv or something else. But my program finished  normally. Its my fault to specify this behavior as SIGSEGV, but the problem exist, map and then unmap a region should make any reference to this region invalid.

Answer (score 0):

> Following code run successfully and message were printed without
>   SIGSEGV. But if I uncommented the printf before munmap, a SIGSEGV were
>   caught.

This prima facie startling behavior has a simple explanation. A *Segmentation fault* is indeed to be expected when accessing unmapped Linux memory. It's just that without the *printf before munmap*, the `printf("Corrupting mmap memory.\n")` after `munmap()` constitutes the program's first use of `stdout`, and on that first use, the Linux/GNU C library allocates a stream buffer by means of `mmap()`, thereby re-mapping exactly the memory page that was unmapped just before, so `p[i]` can access the anew mapped memory without a fault.